# how to get value in dynamic input to sql React

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm a newbie react.I had generated input fields dynamically. Now I want to get values firstName and Lastname in this dynamics input fields to the database but I don't know how to get this value.

please help me

his my code App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{ firstName: "", lastName: "" }]);

  const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...inputList];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setInputList(list);
  };

  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setInputList([...inputList, { firstName: "", lastName: "" }]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {inputList.map((x, i) => {
        return (
          <div className="box">
            <input
              name="firstName"
              placeholder="Enter First Name"
              value={x.firstName}
              onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)}
            />
            <input
              className="ml10"
              name="lastName"
              placeholder="Enter Last Name"
              value={x.lastName}
              onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)}
            />
            <div className="btn-box">
              {inputList.length - 1 === i && <button onClick={handleAddClick}>Add</button>}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>{JSON.stringify(inputList)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve values from server side which means you will do fetch process in browser side. Use useEffect to do fetch call and set the response with setInputList.

The below is one way with useEffect. Depending on your pj concept, you can also use useSwr, SSR or etc where data retrieving happens.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{ firstName: "", lastName: "" }]);

  const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...inputList];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setInputList(list);
  };

  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setInputList([...inputList, { firstName: "", lastName: "" }]);
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    let canExexute = true;

    // Anything to retrieve data such as
    // fetch, graphql query,,,etc

    // Set values from the above
    if (canExecute) setInputList(values)

    // Caring about when unmounting component
    return ()=>{
      canExecute = false;
    }

  // Don't put inputList state itself as dependancies which causes infinite rendering.
  },[dependencies])


  return (
    <div className="App">
      {inputList.map((x, i) => {
        return (
          <div className="box">
            <input
              name="firstName"
              placeholder="Enter First Name"
              value={x.firstName}
              onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)}
            />
            <input
              className="ml10"
              name="lastName"
              placeholder="Enter Last Name"
              value={x.lastName}
              onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)}
            />
            <div className="btn-box">
              {inputList.length - 1 === i && <button onClick={handleAddClick}>Add</button>}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>{JSON.stringify(inputList)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```